# Three20 + CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, three20

Before I begin looking into this myself, I wanted to check if anyone had leads on projects that already integrate CoreData into the three20 MVC model.

I didn't find anything when I looked online so just throwing this out there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really heard of any tight integration, but it shouldn't be that hard to do. All you need to do is have a TTModel subclass provide the data from your CoreData context. Then just wire up the communication for reloading, etc. if needed.

Comment: yea, that's the route I'm going. Looks like it should all line up... I want to try and use NSFetchedResultsController if I can though - it sounds like it'll make displaying results must easier.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid the three20 code base.  It is not the best example of Objective-C out there and is generally more headache than it is worth.

Likewise, because if its *unusual* internal structure it is not going to work with Core Data without a lot of re-writing.  I have done it and I can honestly say that it was not worth the effort and will not be doing it again.

Comment: That's an intriguing perspective on three20. Do you have blog post/writeup anywhere explaining why you believe so?

Comment: No, I have experience working with it. Never bothered to blog about it as it would probably turn mean. I would suggest looking at the class structure to begin with; it is poorly designed.

Comment: I think it's extremely well designed (although terribly documented) and would love to see a blog post with your reasoning.

Comment: It is not unfortunately and I am unlikely to do a blog post about it for the reasons I have already stated.

Comment: Marcus, IMO making a statement like that without backing it up makes you lose credibility, even if you have good reason for why it's bad. If you truly have sound arguments, it shouldn't be hard to articulate them without sounding mean. And you never know - maintainers of Three20 might be mature enough to accept constructive feedback and act on it.

Comment: It is called an opinion, not something to be debated. If you were truly interested in what is wrong with that library you can try Google. There are plenty of people out there who are interested in debating its merit.

Answer (score 0):

Three20 has a template for you to work with Core Data, have a look at it first. Personally in my application, I have used a complex Core Data object model with nearly ten objects and relationships. So, be confident that it already worked for other people.

Comment: Can you post some links? Can't find template you are talking about :(